# Java REST web service constructor

Tags: java, web-services, rest, constructor

Is there any point in having a constructor in a Java Web Service class? (There seems to be no consensus in the articles I have found so far.)

I am using **Jersey** to implement a **REST web service** that needs to have a non-static common object (a string-processing utility class) made available to various (non-static) methods of the service.

Initializing this common object would typically happen in the **constructor** of the class, if that were not a web service. But what about now that it is?

If a constructor cannot be used, should I put, in every relevant method, a **synchronized block** that checks whether the common object is available and, if not, initialize it? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every web service class *does* have a constructor. If you don't include one then Java automatically adds the default no-arg constructor for you. You can:

1. Initialize the utility instance when declaring it's class variable
2. Manually add the default constructor and initialize the utility
   instance in it
3. Or if your using JEE6 you can inject the utility instance into your
   web service

Comment: Options 1 and 2 will do just fine. So, just to confirm, does this mean that I can initialize the utility object via a constructor (as per Option 2), as if the class were not a web service class? And does the constructor need to be public?

Comment: You need at least one public constructor or else the container will not be able to initialize your web service class. In addition, if you are not using JEE6 then the default constructor **must** be public.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an opinion, but if you want to adhere 100% to REST your web service should be stateless. Initializing common objects in web service method calls implies state so it's not the best idea.*

*this is debatable, as can be seen in comments. However any synchronization and shared object initialization if not necesarry IMO should be a no-no in REST applications.

Contructor certainly is a solution, even better one would be to use dependency injection and inject the object you need to your webservice instance at creation.

Comment: I agree about the statelessness, but this is a utility object for optimizing processing, that does not otherwise keep any other state that the web service cares about.

Comment: @PNS you're still better off initializing it in other ways. If only to avoid littering code with innecesary tests.

Comment: Sure, but the constructor initializes, so it would be ideal for this purpose! :-)

Comment: @PNS dependency injection injects only once as well :)

Comment: I am conservative, thus prefer the constructor approach. :-)

Comment: @soulcheck - Statelessness does not imply that your web service class cannot utilize other objects to do its work. Infact I can't imagine a very useful web-service that doesn't.

Comment: @Perception i know. The point is that having a shared object initialized at webservice request does in my opinion introduce unnecesary state (initialized? uninitialized? does user exist in session?).

Comment: Sorry, but that is simply incorrect. Stateful/Stateless with respect to client-server interaction refers to specific information being stored on the server, for the client. It would mean for example, that I could not use the same server instance to service multiple clients simultaneously, because client specific state was being stored in the instance. Nothing about what the OP stated implies that this is the case.

Comment: @Perception well serving multiple clients simultaneously boils down to accessing shared resources (state) in a synchronized manner, wchich is what OP was implying. It was a bad idea anyway and looking at your answer we agree on that.

Answer (score 1):

Try [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmgkd.html) annotation. It might help you.